# VBscript for nested OUs

Tags: api, vbscript, active-directory

I need help in figuring out how to add additional OU's in an API script coded in vbscripting language. I see the variables for the "syncGroupOU" to add the additional ones such as "syncGroupOU2", etc, but do not know how to add it in the line for the LDAP path. 
So if I need to get all the users from a group named "tvusers" in an OU named "myusers", but it is nested through two other OU's then how could I modify this?
The full LDAP path would be: myusers, OUnest2, OUnest1

Please see the script below:

```
' API access token
Dim accessToken
accessToken= "XX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" '<-- your access token, can be left empty when OAuth (below) is configured.

' OAuth: API client id & authorizationCode
Dim clientId, authorizationCode
' if all variables are set here, OAuth will be used to request an access token
clientId = ""               '<-- Create an app in your TeamViewer Management Console and insert the client ID here.
clientSecret = ""           '<-- Insert your client secret here.
authorizationCode = ""      '<-- Visit https://webapi.teamviewer.com/api/v1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOURCLIENTIDHERE
                            '    Login, grant the permissions (popup) and put the code shown in the authorizationCode variable here
' domain settings
Dim dn, dcIP, dcLdapPort, syncGroupCN, syncGroupOU, syncGroupOU2, syncGroupSearchFilter 
dn = "dc=testad,dc=local"   '<--domain components

' LDAP settings
dcIP = "127.0.0.1"
dcLdapPort = "389"

' user group to sync with
syncGroupCN = "tvuser"      '<--groupName
syncGroupOU = "myUsers"     '<--ou

' new user defaults
Dim defaultUserLanguage, defaultUserPassword, defaultUserPermissions
defaultUserLanguage = "en"
defaultUserPassword = "myInitalPassword!"
defaultUserPermissions = "ShareOwnGroups,EditConnections,EditFullProfile,ViewOwnConnections"

' deactivate company users not found in the configured AD group 
Dim deactivateUnknownUsers, testRun 
deactivateUnknownUsers = false
' testRun needs to be set to false for the script to perform actual changes
testRun = true

'#########
' includes
'#########

Sub Include(sInstFile)
    Dim f, s, oFSO
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    If oFSO.FileExists(sInstFile) Then
        Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInstFile)
        s = f.ReadAll
        f.Close
        ExecuteGlobal s
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
    Set f = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Include("Common.vbs")

'###########
' Functions
'###########

' Get All the Members of an AD-Group as dictionary (email as key, dictionary as value)  
Function GetADMembersOfOU() 
    WScript.Echo
    WScript.Echo "Reading AD OU members"
    Dim dictUsersAD
    Set dictUsersAD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")        

    On Error Resume Next
    'with ip:port (on any machine)
    Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & dcIP & ":" & dcLdapPort & "/cn=" & syncGroupCN & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU2 & "," & dn )

    'without ip:port (on AD-Client)
    'Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://"  & "cn=" & syncGroupCN & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU & "," & dn )

    For Each objADUser In objGroup.Members
        if objADUser.AccountDisabled = False Then        
            Set usr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")        
            usr.Add "email", objADUser.Mail
            usr.Add "name", objADUser.GivenName & " " & objADUser.Lastname

            If Len(usr("email")) > 0 AND Len(usr("name")) > 0 Then
                dictUsersAD.Add usr("email"), usr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & dcIP & ":" & dcLdapPort & "/cn=" & syncGroupCN & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU2 & "," & dn )
```

to

```
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://cn=" & syncGroupCN & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU2 & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU & "," & dn)
```

So you should be passing this DistinguishedName:

```
LDAP://cn=tvusers,ou=OUnest1,ou=OUnest2,ou=myusers,dc=testad,dc=local
```

And you are passing, incorrectly, this DistinguishedName:

```
LDAP://cn=tvusers,ou=myusers,ou=OUnest2,ou=OUnest1,dc=testad,dc=local
```

Just to be clear, the build of object goes:

group -> firstparent -> secondparent -> thirdparent -> domain

and you have:

group -> thirdparent -> secondparent -> firstparent -> domain

This is tricky because the folder structure in Active Directory Users and Computers is how you have it, but the LDAP structure is how I posted above.

Comment: Thank you Nathan! I will try this out and update you shortly how it worked out

Comment: Ok it worked! Thanks! Just a quick question though. You mentioned that it should be: group -> firstparent -> secondparent -> thirdparent -> domain, but in the line of code you told me to replace you have the Second parent>First parent so am not sure if I understand quite correctly.

Comment: That's because you say: "The full LDAP path would be: myusers, OUnest2, OUnest1". You have incorrectly named your variables here. I didn't bother changing the variables because I didn't want to confuse the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the `ou` Paths for the nested group. With that, you can nest it until infinity...

`syncGroupOU = "Teamviewer,ou=Parent,ou=moreparent,ou=muchmoreparent"`

But the whole thing is not working if you have not members, but groups as members.

Would be more interesting.

Answer (score -1):

So this worked

```
' domain settings
Dim dn, dcIP, dcLdapPort, syncGroupCN, syncGroupOU, syncGroupSearchFilter 
dn = "dc=tv,dc=support"   '<--domain components

' LDAP settings
dcIP = "127.0.0.1"
dcLdapPort = "389"

' user group to sync with
syncGroupCN = "tvusers"      '<--groupName
syncGroupOU = "OU1"          '<--First parent ou
syncGroupOU2 = "OU2"         '<--Second parent ou

' new user defaults
Dim defaultUserLanguage, defaultUserPassword, defaultUserPermissions
defaultUserLanguage = "en"
defaultUserPassword = "myInitalPassword!"
defaultUserPermissions = "ShareOwnGroups,EditConnections,EditFullProfile,ViewOwnConnections"

' deactivate company users not found in the configured AD group 
Dim deactivateUnknownUsers, testRun 
deactivateUnknownUsers = false
' testRun needs to be set to false for the script to perform actual changes
testRun = false

'#########
' includes
'#########

Sub Include(sInstFile)
    Dim f, s, oFSO
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    If oFSO.FileExists(sInstFile) Then
        Set f = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sInstFile)
        s = f.ReadAll
        f.Close
        ExecuteGlobal s
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
    Set f = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Include("Common.vbs")

'###########
' Functions
'###########

' Get All the Members of an AD-Group as dictionary (email as key, dictionary as value)  
Function GetADMembersOfOU() 
    WScript.Echo
    WScript.Echo "Reading AD OU members"
    Dim dictUsersAD
    Set dictUsersAD = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")        

    On Error Resume Next
    'with ip:port (on any machine)
    'Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & dcIP & ":" & dcLdapPort & "/cn=" & syncGroupCN & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU & "," & dn )

    Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://cn=" & syncGroupCN & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU2 & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU & "," & dn)

    'without ip:port (on AD-Client)
    'Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://"  & "cn=" & syncGroupCN & ",ou=" & syncGroupOU & "," & dn )
```